# Debug ASCX control

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, ascx

I am using a ascx control in my page and I am having a drop down in it which I am not able to load any values in it. Now I want to debug the control. Can some one suggest a way to debug the ascx control?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to add values to the drop down: Using client-side scripting, server-side scripting in the mark-up, code in the code file or something else? There are many ways to add data to a drop down, fyi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug an ascx file like any other file in visual studio. Add a breakpoint, and start the project in visual studio.

Comment: <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload Attachment" /> You can't add a breakpoint on this type of line in ascx file

Answer (score 1):

you cannot set visually a brakepoint in that type of controls
however there is a way to debug javascript in a ASXC file,
Just write  "debugger" in any javascript fucntion and the runtime will stop there.

for example:

function SaveEmployee(message){
debugger
//rest of code

}